# Curl hangs over 2599 bytes response for specific host, where could I investigate?

Tags: networking, curl

I have one server that curls other servers for somepage.php, is does it with over 8 servers now, but the curl doesn't work on only one of them, it simply hangs.

Investigating it further, I noticed that the same curl works if started from other servers or from my own computer.

Also I noticed that if that page returns 1298 characters or less, it works fine, for 1299 or more, it hangs, weird.

Then I thought it could be some weird character in the response, but printing only the letter "x" repeatedly hangs the same way.

Some way, one of my servers doesn't like some other to specifically send over 1298 characters. Why?

The server doing curls is an amazon linux (redhat based) and the others are debians. The request and response headers are the same for everyone.

Oh, and it was working before, it suddenly stopped. Same problem with wget.

Where do I start investigating?

Thanks!

Comment: what if you try with wget?

Comment: Show your complete firewall.

Comment: wget stucks the same way. I've removed all iptables rules and still no luck

Comment: Some form of MTU issue?

Comment: could MTU limit by ip? That's odd